# Jenkins output in firefox console has special characters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

This is the output of running a postman script in jenkins, the command line output of the same command is very clear while that in jenkins looks ugly, I searched through many solutions but was not able to clear it

I run jenkins as a windows service

```
Jenkins demo fixed

â†’ GET copy
  GET echo.getpostman.com/get [200 OK, 725B, 1017ms]
  â”Œ
  â”‚ {}
  â””
  âˆš  Body contains Host
  âˆš  Body contains URL

â†’ Default copy
  POST http://echo.getpostman.com/post [200 OK, 795B, 294ms]
  âˆš  Body contains html
  âˆš  Response time is less than 1000ms

â”Œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”�
â”‚                         â”‚ executed â”‚   failed â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚              iterations â”‚        1 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚                requests â”‚        2 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚            test-scripts â”‚        2 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚      prerequest-scripts â”‚        0 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚              assertions â”‚        4 â”‚        0 â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”´â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”´â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚ total run duration: 1424ms                    â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚ total data received: 521B (approx)            â”‚
â”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚ average response time: 655ms                  â”‚
â””â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”˜
```

Please provide suggestions to clear it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the encoding issue in the Jenkins.

Just include this Java Argument **-Dfile.encoding=UTF8** in **arguments** section of the jenkins.xml file which is in the Jenkins Installation .

Make sure you have the access to edit that file.

Just restart the Jenkins and you can see it working fine.